# Python: Most efficient method to find the most common string

Tags: python, performance, list, pandas

I want to find the 20 most common names, and their frequency, in a country.

Lets say I have lists of all residents' first name in 100 cities. Each list might contain a lot of names. Lets say we speak about 100 lists, each list with 1000 strings.

What is the most **efficient** method to get the 20 most common names, and their frequencies, in the entire country?

This is the direction I began with, assuming I got each city in a text file at the same directory:

1. Use `pandas` and `collection` modules for this.
2. Iterate through each city.txt, making it a string. Then, turn it into a collection using the `Counter` module, and then to a DataFrame (using `to_dict`).
3. Union each DataFrame with the previous one.
4. Then, group by and count (*) the DataFrame.

But, I'm thinking this method might not work, as the DataFrame can get too big.

Would like to hear any advice on that. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `Counter` class from `collections`

Comment: Pandas has `value_counts()` for this.

Comment: How much data are we talking about here?

Comment: I am using it, for each list (see 2, I'll edit to clarify that). However, when you have a 100 lists with 100 strings each - what do you do?

Comment: Please show us the code you already tried and then we can help you. this site is not meant to provide you with the answers to your school assignments.

Comment: This isn't a school assignment, and I don't look for a code snippet, but for an algorithm.

Comment: @Smithnson You need to show us how a file looks like. It's hard to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code:

```
import os
from collections import Counter

cities = [i for i in os.listdir(".") if i.endswith(".txt")]

d = Counter()     

for file in cities:
    with open(file) as f:
        # Adjust the code below to put the strings in a list
        data = f.read().split(",")
        d.update(Counter(data))

out = d.most_common(10)
print(out)
```

Comment: Is this the fastest way? Is there a faster one?

Comment: @Smithnson Yes this is probably the fastest way if you use Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) library, I was using the code below for similar purpose.

```
from nltk import FreqDist
fd = FreqDist(text)    
top_20 = fd.most_commmon(20)        # it's done, you got top 20 tokens :)
```